# How to set up date/time on DGS-1500?

Tags: time, date

I have numerous D-Link DGS-1500-28 switches with firmware 1.00.013, 1.10.005 and 2.10.002 on it, and there are no visible option to set up date/time via web- or telnet-interface.

Device uses date/time in logs, but there is no idea, where it obtains it from: now it is different days in 2009 for 1.00.013, in 2011 for 1.10.005 and in 2012 for 2.001.006. The date showing is even not 01/01/YYYY + system uptime, as it could seems to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This manual for the DGS-1500-20/28/52/28P switches](http://www.dlink.com/-/media/Business_Products/DGS/DGS%201500/Manual/DGS_1500_A1_Manual_v2_11_WW.pdf) describes setting the time manually or via SNTP on page 49. Perhaps you just need to upgrade the firmware (seeing as how this manual is for firmware version 2.11.

Comment: In fact I just didn't find this entry by myself. It works the same way in 2.001.006 firmware. Thank you for what you have found!